# Trying to get the last created/modified subfolder in folder

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

Environment:
Windows 2016 Server Standard
Windows command prompt and batch files

I'm trying to sort the subfolders by DateCreated or DateModified and get the latest folder name.

```
for %%i in ('DIR /AD /OD /B') do echo %%i
```

I was expecting this to give me the name of the last folder in the set. I tested the DIR command and I verified that the last subfolder is indeed I'm looking for. Instead, I get the following result:

```
C:\ProgramData\UPS\install\wpf>
'DIR
/AD
/OD
/B'
```

Comment: `for /F "delims= eol=|" %%i in ('DIR /AD /OD /B') do echo %%i` does the trick; there is no `usebackq` necessary, but `delims=` is to not split file names at the first space…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit

As noted by [@aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl), `delims=` will also work, `usebackq` is a bit overkill for this scenario. And it's better to use `echo %%i & goto :EOF` than `(echo %%i & goto :EOF)` so as to avoid an unnecessary trailing space. So, incorporating the additions mentioned in the comments, one might use the following:

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('DIR /AD /OD /B') do echo %%i & goto :EOF
```

For completion's sake, here's the documentation for `delims=`

> delims=xxx      - specifies a delimiter set.  This replaces the
> default delimiter set of space and tab.

---

#### Initial Answer

The additional option (using the /F flag) you're looking for is "usebackq"

> usebackq        - specifies that the new semantics are in force,
> where a back quoted string is executed as a
> command and a single quoted string is a
> literal string command and allows the use of
> double quotes to quote file names in
> file-set.

So the updated command would be

```
for /F "usebackq" %%i in (`DIR /AD /OD /B`) do echo %%i
```

Note that the single quotes were replaced with "back quotes" (though I've always called them "grave accent" or "back tick"). This makes `for` execute the command in-between them.

Comment: how hard would it be to sort the set descending and just take the first subfolder instead of having to iterate the entire set?

Comment: Quite simple. You can replace the `do echo %%i` with `do (echo %%i & goto :EOF)`

Comment: The `usebackq` option is not necessary here, but `delims=` is to avoid unwanted splitting of file names. And `(echo %%i & goto :EOF)` echoes a trailing space, better use `echo %%i& goto :EOF` or `(echo %%i) & goto :EOF`…

Comment: @aschipfl Good points! +1. I'll add those to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This gives the last date written and the fully qualified path to the directory. It works in a `batch-file` run by `cmd` on `windows`. This needs the most recent Windows PowerShell 5.1 which was released over 5 years ago. It also runs on PowerShell Core https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Property LastWriteTime,FullName"
```

If you could use a PowerShell console, it is easier.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Property LastWriteTime,FullName
```

And typing can be shortened still using aliases. Aliases should not be written into script files.

```
gci -dir -re | sort LastWriteTime | select LastWriteTime,FullName
```